# React native - background color covering only half the screen , how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stylesheet, background-color

I'm new to React Native. I recently converted all my functional components into class components and re-ran my code - but now the background-color covers only half the screen. flex:1 in the styles.container and I tried setting the height and width of the container to 100% in case that was causing the error. But turns out, it stays the same. How do I fix this? [image: Background-color only covering half the screen !]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#d6ffff',
      height: "100%",
      width: "100%"
  }

     class Login extends React.Component {
            render() {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.heading} > Login </Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Email"
              placeholderTextColor="#00bcd4"
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor="#00bcd4"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
                <Button 
                  title="Login" 
                  color='#00bcd4' 
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MainMenu')} />
            </View>
           ); 
         }
        }
    const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Login: Login
      }
    );
    export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Comment: If possible could you share your source code.

Comment: Try adding display: 'flex' to the container class.

Comment: @MazharHaque added it, shows the same

Comment: @SDushan, showing - one moment

Comment: @SDushan please see the editted question - iv put in my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

{
   .... Your code
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#d6ffff',
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it solved the problem for half of the pages - coming to full screen now, but others it is still half. but, thanks !

Comment: Hi, why using height and width, instead of just flex:1 ? It should work and cover all of your screen no ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#d6ffff',
  }
})
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27273890).

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to width and height properties:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#d6ffff',
  }
})
```